# Generating a Nakagami Random Variable

Tags: random

Assuming the only tool for generating random numbers I have available is generating a uniformly distributed variable `u` on U(0,1). I want to generate a [Nakagami Random Variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution) from it.

I know I could just plug `u` into the inverse CDF of the Nakagami distribution, but unfortunately, the inverse CDF isn't trivial to compute.

Comment: In the worst case one can always use an approximation of the inverse CDF combining it with a rejection function to arrive at the precise distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Which difficulties do you have computing the CDF?  Special functions gamma and \Gamma are availble in scientific computing libraries.

If the CDF-based method will not do, you can generate Nagakami distributed numbers based on Gamma distributed numbers or Chi distributed numbers.  The methods are described in Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution